# How do I add time-stamp information to Maven artifacts?

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, upgrade

I am upgrading a large build-system to use Maven2 instead of Ant, and we have two related requirements that I'm stuck on:

1. We need to generate a time-stamped artifact, so a part of the *package*
   phase (or wherever), instead of building

   ```
   project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
   ```

   we
   should be building

   ```
   project-1.0-20090803125803.jar
   ```

   (where the
   `20090803125803` is just a `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` time-stamp of when the jar is
   built).

   The only real requirement is that the time-stamp be a part of the
   generated file's filename.
2. The same time-stamp has to be included within a *version.properties* file
   inside the generated jar.

This information is included in the generated *pom.properties* when you run,
e.g., `mvn package` but is commented out:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Mon Aug 03 12:57:17 PDT 2009
```

Any ideas on where to start would be helpful!  Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Maven versions 2.1.0-M1 or newer have built in special variable `maven.build.timestamp`.

```
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
</build>
```

See Maven [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables) for more details.

---

For older Maven versions a look at [maven-timestamp-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-timestamp-plugin/) or [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/index.html).

If you use maven-timestamp-plugin, you can use something like this to manipulate resulting artifact name.

```
<build>
   <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${timestamp}</finalName>
</build>
```

And this configuration for buildnumber-maven-plugin should create a ${timestamp} property which contains the timestamp value. There doesn't seem to be a way to create the *version.properties* file directly with this plugin.

```
<configuration>
   <format>{0,date,yyyyMMddHHmmss}</format>
   <items>
      <item>timestamp</item>
   </items>

</configuration>
```

[These](http://apollo.ucalgary.ca/tlcprojectswiki/index.php/Public/Project_Versioning_-_Best_Practices#Build_Versioning) 
 [three](http://www.gadberry.com/aaron/2007/05/28/inject-build-time-timestamp-property-using-maven/)  [sites](http://pteropus.blogspot.com/2007/03/from-maven-to-mvn-part-5.html) are also worth checking out.

Comment: You may be able to create your version.properties file by stubbing it out in /src/main/resources and using filtering.  Then use the ${timestamp} property in the filter.  The trick would be getting the ${timestamp} property created before the filters are applied.

Comment: Just in case some stumbles over this old answer like me: It is now build in: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

Comment: But wouldn't `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${timestamp}` will generate `project-1.0-SNAPSHOT-20090803125803` ?

Comment: The format of the build timestamp can be customized by declaring the property `maven.build.timestamp.format` which follows Java `SimpleDateFormat` patterns

Comment: No clue why, but Maven's timestamp does not use current timezone, so I would not consider this answer a solution

Answer (score 41):

If you use a version of Maven >= 2.1.0-M1, then you can use the ${maven.build.timestamp} property.

For more info, see: 
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

Comment: I prefer this one as no plugin is needed.

Comment: If you use maven-war-plugin just add this in configuration: `<configuration>...<warName>${project.name}-${project.version}_${maven.build.timestamp}</warName></configuration>`

Comment: This will always result the time in UTC format, if you want the time in another timezone use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin: Search for *timezone* in [http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: @lmiguelmh "This will always result the time in UTC format" I use Maven 3.0.5 and `${maven.build.timestamp}` displays in the local time zone, not UTC. Maybe that's a recent change in Maven.

Answer (score 19):

This post  (especially the below part)  is also very useful and practical for this issue.

[Stamping Version Number and Build Time in a Properties File with Maven](http://java.dzone.com/tips/stamping-version-number-and)

The pom will look like this

```
...
<properties>
        
        ....
        
        <!-- Timestamp of build  -->
        <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
        
</properties>

...

<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${timestamp}</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                ....
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
....
```

and the package name is **`MyProject-1.0.0-2015_03_02_13_46.war`**

Comment: Link to post is broken.  Link that works:  https://dzone.com/articles/stamping-version-number-and

Answer (score 16):

If you need the time in a timezone other than UTC (the default when you use `${maven.build.timestamp}`) you could use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`. See more in [Brief examples on how to use the Build Helper Maven Plugin's goals](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Anyway, this is how I've got the *timestamp in GMT-5* and put it in the final name of my artifact:

```
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.9.1</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>timestamp-property</id>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <name>current.time</name>
                          <pattern>yyyyMMdd-HHmmss</pattern>
                          <timeZone>GMT-5</timeZone>
                      </configuration>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
              <configuration>
                  <finalName>${project.name}-${current.time}</finalName>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

When a SNAPSHOT project is deployed, by default a timestamp is used unless you override it in the [deploy plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/disabling-timestamps-suffix.html). If you're not getting unique timestamps, it is probably down to a configuration of your Maven repository. As the other answer says though, use the timestamp or buildnumber plugin for releases.

Comment: Doesn't work like this here. Can you elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 1):

We need a newer answer :)
It is build in now: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables

use `${maven.build.timestamp}`