# How can I backup file using pom.xml?

Tags: xml, maven, tags

I've got three questions here. First, does pom.xml of maven have any difference from other xml file?

Second, if I would like to rename a file in the same directory as the pom.xml by scripts, can I do it in pom.xml? If possible, then how should I do it?

Last, how can I get the current time in pom.xml?

In fact, what I want to achieve is that I would like to backup the current package(.war) by appending it with the timestamps before I mvn package it. I want the whole process automated by the pom.xml instead of manually processing it.

Hi there,

I find a way to get the timestamp, will it work?

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactID>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <execution>
  <phrase>package</phrase>
  <configuration>
    <format>{0, date, yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</format>
    <items>timestamp</items>  
  </configuration>
  <execution>
</plugin>
```

will it work? if it works, how can I obtain the timestamp variable? $items or $timestamp?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Maven `pom.xml` is just another XML file and there is no difference from others. It follows the same XML standards.

Now for Question 2 and 3, First of all, when you will run `mvn clean`, it will flush off all the files, including the `war` from the target folder.

You can run [ANT](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) tasks to rename and backup the current war, but it cannot be executed before clean.
I would suggest you the following approach:

- Run `maven-antrun-plugin` as a part of `package` goal.
- In the `ANT` target, rename and backup the current packaged war.

**Alternatively**:
What I would suggest is: In the `WAR` *pom.xml*, specify the `<version>` element with the current timestamp and the desired version. This way, each war would be copied into different directories in the maven local repository.

**PS: You cannot generate timestamp in maven as per my knowledge. Pass it through some external variable**

Comment: hi friend, running maven-antrun-plugin looks good good. but I can only <copy ...> some files, I don't the tag of rename. Can you provide it to me with an example illustrating its usage, please? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: and please note that I have found a way to find the timestamps by an plugin. How can I embed it in the name of the file which is going to be backuped.

Comment: Yes, you can only copy the artifact(`WAR`) after packaging.  Need not move it.  `<copy file="[current_location]\MyWar.war" tofile="[new_location]\MyWar_${timestamp}.war" />`

Comment: looks good! everything works fine except the method I found does not work. it just give me the xxx_${timestamp} instead of real time there. hm...what's wrong with the codes?

Comment: the official website does not show much detail about it : http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html

Comment: How are you calling your POM's ? You can pass the timestamp variable there itself ... `mvn clean install -Dtimestamp="08/05/2011 03:03:00"`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should set the context for your questions to get better answers. Anyway, here goes.

- pom.xml is an xml file, with its own [schema](http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd).  Thus it is different from *other* xml files.
- There are a couple of ways to rename a file using maven.  [This SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998596/renaming-resources-in-maven) gives the options.  One of them is as follows:

Essentially, you would have a pom with entries similar to the one in [this example](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) (external `build.xml`).  Your `ant` `build.xml` would have entries similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="dummy">
    ...
    <target name="rename">
        <move file="file.orig" tofile="file.moved"/>
    </target>
    ...
</project>
```

- You can use a special maven variable for timestamp as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).  Refer to this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224359/how-do-i-add-time-stamp-information-to-maven-artifacts) on how to use it.

  maven.build.timestamp   The timestamp that denotes the start of the build. Since Maven 2.1.0-M1

Comment: Thanks a lot! your explanation is detailed and helpful. It would be a great help if you can give me an example of codes showing me how to rename file, because the link you've just given is too difficult for me to understand. Thanks,